# I wish to change the format of the numbers contained in a list Common Lisp Allegro

Tags: floating-point, formatting, lisp, common-lisp

I have lists which contain numbers with too many decimals. I would like to recondition the list changing the format of the list elements. For instance I have '( 1.233453923729 3.44566546  9.1111111) and I would like to keep max two decimals.

I tried with a dolist to extract the list component to write them on a stream and to reread them after correcting the format. Actually I don't know how to write data on a string stream and then reading them again after format correction.

Comment: If you show the code you tried using to format and parse, maybe we can help with that; this is not a recommended way to use strings in that case but it might be interesting to at least learn how it can be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply your float by a power of 10, call [`FROUND`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_floorc.htm) and divide by the same factor:

```
(defun round-float (float places)                      
  (check-type places (integer 1))
  (let ((factor (expt 10 places)))                     
    (/ (fround (* float factor)) factor)))
```

Then you can apply the same function to all your floats using [`MAPCAR`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_mapc_.htm):

```
(mapcar (lambda (f) (round-float f 2)) floats)
```

Comment: Great !!! Simple and efficient. No need for writing and reading on streams.Thank you coredump. Only one further question. Mapcar should be given to my list with a furter argument, the number of decimals wanted. (Mapcar #'round-float mylist ndec) does not seem to work. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @ponipei I edited the answer (you can upvote/accept the answer if you find it good: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Ok  I got it. The argument  must be given as a list with a number of decimals for each element of the original list. Thank you coredump. !!

Comment: Note that floating-point numbers don't use decimal. If you, say, truncate a value down to the nearest 1/100th (0.01) so there are only two digits of precision, you will actually get only a very close approximation of that fractional number.  (Very close, like to 15 digits of precision). That close approximation might print funny. E.g. instead of 4.13, you might get 4.1299999999999997 if you print the value to its full precision. You still need  to round the values  to the desired number of digits when printing.